# why is my UIButton in TitleView not working

Tags: swift

I have a custom view containing an **UIButton** that I want to use as **titleView**:

```
let titleView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TitleView", owner: self,
 options: nil)?[0] as? TitleView
titleView?.title.text = self.title        
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = titleView
```

The button is linked with an **IBAction** in it's class.
The View is displayed correctly in the navigation bar, but the button is not working. It doesn't even get highlighted during the touch. Looks like something is preventing the touch event.

[image: screen]

Comment: Hello. show full code

Comment: not sure what else to show you, the view ist just a subclass of UView with an outlet and an action that never gets called. I can't upload the whole app

Comment: Send screen of attribute inspector of your button and controller (right side of Xcode)

Comment: i added a screen of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code below to your titleView

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize
}
```

Comment: thanks, I don't understand what it does, but it works.